# Vertical slide with Reveal.js and Rmarkdown

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

I was trying to make some slides through reveal.js and Rmarkdown in RStudio. I run into a problem with vertical slides. Whenever I set the next slide with "###", the next slide would be embedded into the last slide. What's the right syntax to set the next slide as a vertical slide (downward)?

```
---
title: "Slide"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    center: true
---

## R Markdown 

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

### Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use one hash less. Documented [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/revealjs_presentation_format.html#2-d_presenations).

```
---
title: "Slide"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    center: true
---

# R Markdown 

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```